# Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists. What does this message mean? Do I need to recover Tomcat if I get it?

Tags: shell, tomcat, tomcat7, cron, recover

I am making a shell script to restart tomcat after crash.
I wonder I need to handle this message in my script "Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists."
What does this message means?
Do I need to take it into account as an error message that oblige me to restart Tomcat?

My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=/etc/init.d/tomcat7
STOPPED_MESSAGE=" * Tomcat servlet container is not running."  
PID_FILE_MESSAGE=" * Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists."

if [ "`$SERVICE status`" == "$STOPPED_MESSAGE" ];
then  
{
    $SERVICE start
}
else
    if [ "`$SERVICE status`" == "$PID_FILE_MESSAGE" ];
    then
    {
        $SERVICE restart
    }
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You should be looking at exit codes, not text output.

Comment: Thank you @jordanm, can you post an example of how we can look at the exit codes?

Comment: `$SERVICE status; if (( $? == 0 )); then echo "running"; fi`. If you are using Linux, LSB defines which exit codes should be provided: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the definition of [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). A PID file is a file that contains a process identifier. If Tomcat's startup scripts are run with `CATALINA_PID` environment variable set properly, then the PID of the Tomcat process will be recorded to a file upon startup. If the file exists when you try to start Tomcat, the scripts will refuse to run because it does not want to clobber a (possibly valid) PID file.

If you are sure that Tomcat is not running, simply delete the file (it should be available through the `CATALINA_PID` environment variable) and try again.

I share @jordanm's comment about using exit codes instead of checking for specific (text) output: the latest version of Tomcat does not even use the messages that you have shown above, so it's very fragile.

If you want a self-re-starting service, considering looking at [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html), which actually ships with Tomcat binaries in source form.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your answer, however I would like to know why "Tomcat servlet engine is not running" but "a possibly valid PID file exists"? when this case happens? what should I do in then if I have this message?

Comment: Please re-read my answer: it provides answers to both of the questions you (re-)ask in your comment.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, excuse me for my quick reaction.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem when i restart the tomcat. Also i found "`java.net.BindException`: Cannot assign requested address" in cataline.out log file.

**Soultion:** Kill all the java pid by using `killall -9 java` the restart the **tomcat** again.

For me problem has been resolved